# c# How To Use .Contains on Generic IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, generics, ienumerable, contains

I'm trying to create a generic method that I want to use for mixing a list of objects based off a property. Optionally, you can supply a list of list objects to merge some groups together. This works fine as a non-generic method and when I code the property manually, etc.

Method head:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MixObjectsByProperty<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> objects,
    string propertyName,
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> groupsToMergeByProperty = null)
```

Snippet of the methods body:

```
groups =
    (from item in objects
    let propertyInfo = item.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)
    where propertyInfo != null
    group item by groupsToMergeByProperty
        .FirstOrDefault(ids => ids.Contains(propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null)))
        //.FirstOrDefault(ids => ids.Any(propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null)))
        ?.First()
        ?? propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null)
    into itemGroup
    select itemGroup.ToArray())
    .ToList();
```

As you can see, I'm having trouble using the contains method on a `IEnumerable<T>` as `propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null)` is returning an object. I've tried various casting attempts and using `.Any()` instead, but I've hit a brick wall :(

Any help will be great, thanks!

Also, let me know if you need any more information but I guess, in essence, all I need to know is how to use `.Contains()` using `<T>`.

Set them to the same type? Custom `IEqualityComparer`?

Comment: Why not just cast result of `GetValue` to `T`?

Comment: If you can constrain `T` to a base type or interface, it'll help massively.

Comment: You can't unless you cast `T` to a specific type else it's known

Comment: Why pass the property name? Why not pass an *expression* like all LINQ methods, eg use `Func<T,T> propGetter` and pass `it =>it.PropName` as the parameter value. Or pass the entire condition as an expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the whole method (because your type signatures clearly indicate it's not the whole method), here's an example implementation:

```
public class Ext
{
    public static List<T[]> MixObjectsByProperty<T, TProp, U>(
        IEnumerable<T> source,
        Expression<Func<T, TProp>> property,
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<U>> groupsToMix = null)
        where T : class
        where U : TProp
    {
        var prop = (PropertyInfo)(property.Body as MemberExpression)?.Member;
        if (prop == null) throw new ArgumentException("Couldn't determine property");

        var accessor = property.Compile();

        var groups = 
            from item in source
            let value = (U)accessor(item)
            group item by
                groupsToMix.FirstOrDefault((ids => ids.Contains(value)))
            into itemGroup
            select itemGroup.ToArray();
        return groups.ToList();
    }
}
```

**For the love of god** stop passing property names and using reflection, the rest of Linq makes use of the gorgeous expression system, and you should too!

Comment: Ok, woah, calm down :P Thanks for the input, it looks nice - I wasn't aware of that. However, can you get your linq to return as List<T[]> please? Then i can fully test this potential solution - thanks :)

Comment: @user2439970 sure thing, there you go!

Comment: Why in the world pass an expression if you're only ever going to just compile it.  Just accept a delegate if you only want a delegate.

Comment: @Servy true, though the expression is useful if the OP wants to get additional information like the property name for debugging purposes etc.

Comment: At which point you're back to just using reflection code, rather than actually having a statically typed system.

Comment: @Clint Thanks! I modified it slightly but the core of what you provided was a nice and neater solution - thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried various casting attempts

Have you tried this one?

```
.FirstOrDefault(ids => ids.Contains((T)propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null)))
```

Since `ids` is of type `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` where `TElement` is of type `T` in your case, casting the value of property to `T` will allow for the comparison.

Comment: I tried that but funnily enough, I tried it again earlier and with a few more tweaks I have it working! :) I'll post the answer now so others can see what I did, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I cracked it in the end. I needed to add more detail in my generic method header/signature.

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> MixObjectsByProperty<T, U>(
        IEnumerable<T> objects, string propertyName, IEnumerable<IEnumerable<U>> groupsToMergeByProperty = null)
        where T : class
        where U : class
    {
        ...
```

Note, I added class constraints which allows me to use nullable operators, etc.

And the body became (after adding a propertyValue variable which is casted to the correct type!):

```
            groups =
                (from item in objects
                 let propertyInfo = item.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)
                 where propertyInfo != null
                 let propertyValue = (U)propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null)
                 group item by
                     groupsToMergeByProperty
                         .FirstOrDefault(ids => ids.Contains(propertyValue))
                         ?.First()
                     ?? propertyValue
                 into itemGroup
                 select itemGroup.ToArray())
                .ToList();
```